# Using regex in Google Analytics to filter out search resulting in not found

Tags: regex, google-analytics, filtering

Our site overwrites empty search results with virtual pageviews, which copy the URL and add prefix such as /empty-listing/ on the beginning.

This results in pages such as

```
/empty-listing/consumer-electronics/smartphones,_Sony,h6,i4,m2:3.html.
```

_Sony, h6, i4 and m2 are parameters by which you can filter products on our site.

If you add multiple criteria (such as Memory: 4GB and 8GB and 16GB) to the same filter, it would results in

```
/.../m2:3:4.html
```

instead of

```
/.../m2,m3,m4.html.
```

What I would love to do is being able to write such a regex, that would match only URL's that have only one parameter to see which one results in no products listed.

A regex that would match both

```
/empty-listing/consumer-electronics/smartphones,_Sony.html
/empty-listing/consumer-electronics/consoles,h6.html
```

but **wouldn't** match

```
/empty-listing/consumer-electronics/smartphones,_Sony,j2.html
```

nor

```
/empty-listing/consumer-electronics/consoles,h5:6,f3.html
```

I would be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching commas seems the way to go: anything that has 0 or 1 comma is OK.

```
^/empty-listing/([^,]*,)?[^,]*$
```

This regex will work on any platform as it doesn't use anything fancy like a look ahead.

Comment: Alright, regex tester confirmed, that it would find the URL's I needed, but this provides me with every possible URL tracked by Google Analytics that has 0 or 1 comma. Where in this regex should I include /empty-listing/ to filter out results that don't have this prefix?

Comment: @Matt no problem: just add `/empty-listing/`, or even `/empty-listing/consumer-electronics/`, to the front of the regex. See edited regex.

Comment: Yay, it worked! Got some great, actionable results with it. I see one last problem, that would provide me with crystal-clear regex filtering results, that is price parameter. It is added as 

,from300to600 

I could add an 

AND Exclude Matching RegExp from|to 

rule within GA, but would it be possible to optimize the regex you have done to include it as well?

Comment: Try excluding this regex `.*from\d+to\d+.*`